# Adding URL's in Awesome-CV template

Tags: hyperref, templates, cv, awesome-cv

I am using [Awesome Latex template.](http:///https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) I wish to include an URL link with some link colors. In the template, the hyperref package is already used with hidelinks option. When I try to include a link, there is some issue coming and the file is not getting compiled. How do I include a URL with link without messing up the class file.
Example: In presentation section, In the title of the talk, I want to give the pdf link with some color.

```
  \cventry
    {Presenter for <Hosting Web Application for Free utilizing GitHub, Netlify and CloudFlare>} % Role
    {DevFest Seoul by Google Developer Group Korea} % Event
    {Seoul, S.Korea} % Location
    {Nov. 2017} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Introduced the history of web technology and the JAM stack which is for the modern web application development.}
        \item {Introduced how to freely host the web application with high performance utilizing global CDN services.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
```

This one is not working.

```
  \cventry
    {Presenter for <Hosting Web Application for Free utilizing GitHub, Netlify and CloudFlare>} % Role
   \href{DevFest Seoul by Google Developer Group Korea}{link1} % Event
    {Seoul, S.Korea} % Location
    {Nov. 2017} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Introduced the history of web technology and the JAM stack which is for the modern web application development.}
        \item {Introduced how to freely host the web application with high performance utilizing global CDN services.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
```

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Your used template has been deleted under your given link. With my local copy I could test your both commands `\cventry`. In your second command you missed an pair of brackets `{...}` like this:

```
\cventry
    {Presenter for <Hosting Web Application for Free utilizing GitHub, Netlify and CloudFlare>} % Role
   {\href{DevFest Seoul by Google Developer Group Korea}{link1}} % Event <==================
    {Seoul, S.Korea} % Location
    {Nov. 2017} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Introduced the history of web technology and the JAM stack which is for the modern web application development.}
        \item {Introduced how to freely host the web application with high performance utilizing global CDN services.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
```

With the following complete code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Awesome Resume/CV
% XeLaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (27/3/2017)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Claud D. Park (posquit0.bj@gmail.com) with modifications by 
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template must be compiled with XeLaTeX, the below lines will ensure this
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter

\geometry{left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm} % Configure page margins with geometry

\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts

% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

% Colors for text - uncomment and modify
%\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{text}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{414141}

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{Claud D.}{Park}
\address{246-1002, Gwangmyeongmayrouge Apt. 86, Cheongna lime-ro, Seo-gu, Incheon-si, 404-180, Rep. of KOREA}
\mobile{(+82) 10-9030-1843}

\email{posquit0.bj@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{posquit0}
\linkedin{posquit0}
%\skype{skypeid}
%\stackoverflow{SOid}{SOname}
%\twitter{@twit}
%\linkedin{linkedin name}
%\reddit{reddit account}
%\xing{xing name}
%\extrainfo{test} % Other text you want to include on this line

\position{Software Engineer{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert} % Your expertise/fields
\quote{``Make the change that you want to see in the world."} % A quote or statement

\makecvfooter{\today}{Claud D. Park~~~·~~~Résumé}{\thepage} % Specify the letter footer with 3 arguments: (<left>, <center>, <right>), leave any of these blank if they are not needed

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CV/RESUME CONTENT
%   Each section is imported separately, open each file in turn to modify content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{cv-sections/education.tex}

\cventry
    {Presenter for <Hosting Web Application for Free utilizing GitHub, Netlify and CloudFlare>} % Role
    {DevFest Seoul by Google Developer Group Korea} % Event
    {Seoul, S.Korea} % Location
    {Nov. 2017} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Introduced the history of web technology and the JAM stack which is for the modern web application development.}
        \item {Introduced how to freely host the web application with high performance utilizing global CDN services.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
    
\cventry
    {Presenter for <Hosting Web Application for Free utilizing GitHub, Netlify and CloudFlare>} % Role
   {\href{DevFest Seoul by Google Developer Group Korea}{link1}} % Event <==================
    {Seoul, S.Korea} % Location
    {Nov. 2017} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s)
        \item {Introduced the history of web technology and the JAM stack which is for the modern web application development.}
        \item {Introduced how to freely host the web application with high performance utilizing global CDN services.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }

\input{cv-sections/skills.tex}
\input{cv-sections/experience.tex}

\newpage % Force a new page for looks

\input{cv-sections/extracurricular.tex}
\input{cv-sections/honors.tex}
\input{cv-sections/presentation.tex}
\input{cv-sections/writing.tex}
\input{cv-sections/committees.tex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

I can compile without errors to the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Hi :-), peraphs after POSTECH is preferible a blank space. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano HI :-) You found an typo in the template example cv. Good catch!

Comment: ahahahahahha LOL :-) I won't be able to forget a concise evaluation when I was a kid: a teacher wrote to me that I had a keen sense of observation.